# How secure is Vagrant/Puppet/Puphpet?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I am sorry if my question is stupid, but I think it is better to be safe than sorry. I am just a beginner when it comes to server configurations and DevOps.

I am checking server configuration management tools like Vagrant/Puppet/Puphpet. They look like extremely powerful tools, but I am worried about the security of using them in the production environment.

For example, when deploying to AWS, we need to specify the AWS access credentials (key and secret, and the key pair). If using Puphpet, you actually need to insert them into the website to create the script file. I downloaded the script as is, and replaced the credentials in the code, but still I wonder how secure it is to trust these external tools (vagrant/puppet) to manage configurations on the server.

Am I just being paranoid, or is this a possible security risk?

Comment: You should distinguish between Puphpet, which is a web service that helps you build Puppet/Vagrant-based system configurators, and Puppet, Vagrant, and the other tools that the generated configurators rely upon.  Their risk profiles are completely different, and largely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I agree about puphpet more risky than the other, especially when you tell it all your credentials. The question remains how secure are the scripts of Vagrant and puppet? Is it possible that there is a backdoor or an exploit there? I know that these tools have many users and good feedback, but strictly from security point of view, is it possible that it is a risk?

Comment: I believe you missed the point of John's comment. He is pointing out that you need to address them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Creator of PuPHPet here. Your configs are not saved to the server, everything is deleted.

I suggest on the GUI you leave the entry blank and manually type it into the yaml file afterward.

PuPHPet's source code is open source, and you are more than welcome to go through all the Puppet modules included in the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant, Puppet and puPHPet are all different fro each other. 
 (1)Vagrant helps you spawn VMs with pre-defined/custom boxes within seconds. The configuration from "Vagrantfile" is applied on the boxes. You can bring up a server and apply your puppet code through it. 
 (2)puPHPet does the same thing but has a nice GUI and higher level of abstraction as compared to vagrant. It has various options to choose when it comes to the kind of box you want. 
 (3)Puppet is configuration management tool with a descriptive language where you write a module and apply it to your server to configure it.

Now coming to security, If you have keys/passwords in your manifests, I will not suggest you to use online tool. But you can install vagrant on your local-machine and use it. If your puppet code is internal to the devops team you work for, its pretty safe to ave passwords in it.

NOTE: NEVER SAVE PASSWORDS IN CODE.